# Why is string concatenation necessary?

Tags: php

```
$lions = "lions";
$tigers = "tigers";
$bears = "bears";

echo "$lions and $tigers and $bears, oh my!"
```

Echos the same thing as this:

```
echo $lions .  " and " . $tigers . " and " . $bears . ", oh my!"
```

So why is concantenation necessary? What is the point?

Comment: Because interpolation only allows for plain variables or basic varexpressions, but concatenation opens the way for expressions like `"there are " . (1 + 2 ) . $lions . " or $bears"`.

Comment: In the `echo` statement variables will be interpolated into values thanks to the double quotes.  But in one example, you may be calling a function that will return a string that you want appended to another string, so concatenation operator is needed.

Comment: I like to have lots of tools in my toolbox, but if you just want a hammer for everything, that's fine.

Comment: [Enough answers here](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=php+string+concatenation+vs+interpolation&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&oq=php+string+concatetion&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.11798j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 3):

It allows you to do this:

```
echo lions() . " and " . tigers();
```

Function calls, and expressions in general, aren't possible using string interpolation.

Special care is also necessary when variable names aren't clearly delineated, e.g.

```
echo "{$lions}_{$tigers}";
```

*The underscore would otherwise be seen as part of the `$lions` variable name.*

Another way to accomplish a similar thing is the use of [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf) and friends:

```
printf('<span>%s</span> and %s', htmlspecialchars($lions), tigers());
```

It all comes down to being able to do certain things in certain situations ;-)

Comment: @Jack OP Is not looking for an error, rather what does each do within the individual cases and how they truly differ

Comment: @DarylGill I'm sorry if the answer doesn't live up to what you expect of it; I'm not sure what you meant by "not looking for an error" though.

Answer (score -1):

They also allow for people to use ' instead of " `echo 'Hello '.$world;`